# Pass more than one parameter in URL

Tags: python, url, parameter-passing

I tried to pass more than one parameter through URL using python, i wrote as this:

```
 self.response.out.write("""<html><br><body><center> <li ><a href="download.py?blob_key=%s & width=%s & height=%s" >%s</a></center></body></html>      
""" % (str(blob_key),str(w),str(h), str(name)))
```

but i can't pass through this method,i don't know the error exactly.
Thanks

Comment: Apart from the whitespace, as the answer points out, I bet you're getting a `TypeError` you didn't even mention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is whitespace. HTTP protocol doesn't tolerate it in request strings.

I would write that like this:

```
'<a href="download.py?key={}&width={}&height={}">{}</a>'.format(key, w, h, name)
```

([**`str.format`**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) is the new preferred alternative to `str%something`).

Comment: :Sorry this part of code in python page i will edit the question

Comment: If you want this to work in python 2.6 then stick the numbers 0 to 3 in the curly brackets: key={0}&width={1} and so on. Empty curlies is a 2.7ism.

Comment: @Spacedman : i used python2.5 and i tried as you say :َ**self.response.out.write("""<html><br><body style="background-color:#CC9999"><center> <li ><a href="download.py?blob_key={0}& w={1}& h={2}">{3}</a>
               </center></body></html>            
                """ % blob_key,w,h,name)َ**, but the problem now is :** TypeError: write() takes exactly 2 arguments (5 given) **

Comment: yes but you've use ' string % value,value ' instead of 'string.format(value,value,...). Most of your value arguments went to the 'write' function. Do: self.response.out.write("etc etc {0} etc etc {1} ertc etc {2} etc etc{3}etcetc".format(v1,v2,v3,v4))